# iOS StoreKit multiple auto subscriptions

Tags: swift, storekit

is it possible to have multiple auto subscriptions like this:

- All - every feature is unlocked -> 4.99$ per week
- Feature 1 - Only feature 1 is unlocked -> 2.99$ per week
- Feature 2 - Only feature 2 is unlocked -> 2.99$ per week
- Feature 3 - only feature 3 is unlocked -> 2.99$ per week

PS. Price of every auto subcription is just for reference.

Users can auto subscribe to all features individually, but its cheaper to subscribe to All.
So, it is possible to subscribe to Feature 1, Feature 2, Feature 3 seperately and should not be possible to switch from subscribed feature to other feature not paying 2.99 as user could try out all features just by paying for one.

If I were to create every auto subscription in its own group then user would probably get billed for all subsriptions if user subcribed to features individually and later decided to go All route. All subcription should cancel out billing of other Features.

If I were to create every subcription inside one group then user could switch Feature subscriptions paying only 2.99?

I can't seem to solve this.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?  I’m facing the exact same problem…